# Which GitHub repo does one fork with there is a pending PR?

Tags: github

Given a github project `A`, there is a fork `B` that has submitted a `PR` which is still pending.

I would like to submit a `PR` which is based on `B` and adds some missing features.

Which of the repos do I fork?

Comment: To be clear, is the ultimate repository you want to merge into A or B?

Comment: Merge with A since that is the original project.